# scapy not getting HTTP requests on non-standard ports

Tags: python, scapy, packet-sniffers

I'm trying to get all HTTP GET/POST incoming requests.

I've found this code which seems promising, but I've noticed that it only works on standard HTTP ports. If I use another port (say 8080) scapy can't find the HTTP layer (packet.haslayer(http.HTTPRequest) == False).

This is the code:

```
from scapy.all import IP, sniff
from scapy.layers import http


def process_tcp_packet(packet):
    '''
    Processes a TCP packet, and if it contains an HTTP request, it prints it.
    '''
    if not packet.haslayer(http.HTTPRequest):
        # This packet doesn't contain an HTTP request so we skip it
        return
    http_layer = packet.getlayer(http.HTTPRequest)
    ip_layer = packet.getlayer(IP)
    print '\n{0[src]} just requested a {1[Method]} {1[Host]}{1[Path]}'.format(ip_layer.fields, http_layer.fields)

# Start sniffing the network.
sniff(filter='tcp', prn=process_tcp_packet)
```

Any idea about what I'm doing wrong?

**** UPDATE ****

I got rid of scapy_http and just looked at the raw data.
I'm posting here the code I'm using - it works fine for me as I'm debugging a strange problem I'm having on Apache Solr - but your mileage may vary.

```
def process_tcp_packet(packet):
  msg = list()
  try:
    if packet.dport == 8983 and packet.haslayer(Raw):
      lines = packet.getlayer(Raw).load.split(os.linesep)

      # GET or POST requests ?
      if lines[0].lower().startswith('get /') or lines[0].lower().startswith('post /'):

        # request forwarded by a proxy ?
        _ = [line.split()[1] for line in lines if line.startswith('X-Forwarded-For:')]
        s_ip = (_[0] if _ else packet.getlayer(IP).src)

        # collect info
        d_port = packet.getlayer(IP).dport
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        msg.append('%s: %s > :%i -> %s' % (now, s_ip, d_port, lines[0]))

  except Exception, e:
    msg.append('%s: ERROR! %s' % (datetime.datetime.now(), str(e)))
    pass

  with open('http.log', 'a') as out:
    for m in msg:
      out.write(m + os.linesep)
```

Comment: which `scapy` http implementation are you using? `http` is not part of the standard `scapy` library

Comment: thanks for the reply. I've installed it using "pip install scapy_http" however, I've used a different approach in the end (I've updated the question).